# Install webapp on IP address

Tags: php, yii, ip, web-hosting

Hello I create yii app in temp IP address like this

```
http://74.220.215.220/~cineklik/
```

but links in my project not work how can me fix that ?

I think I need to modify WebRoot in Yii.. but I don't know how ?

**hint:**
producted/comfig/main.php

```
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
...
```

Comment: You cannot install a webapp on an IP address. You can install it on a server that has a specific IP address. What you probably meant was that you try to access it by IP address instead of hostname. Please edit the question and clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of things i suppose at this point are unclear. As @Tibor said i donot know what do you mean by that. If your home or index page is opening but inner pages are not you may have modified the UrlManager or you would have to modify it. Can you paste code in config/main.php (UrlManager code)

Following is By default

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

If above is not commented try by commenting it out to see if pages show up or not

Answer (score 0):

You may create a rewrite rule, like

```
~cineklik/(.*)    $1
```

or an [output processor](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/COutputProcessor) which processes all your link URLs after the content has been rendered.

It's best practice to use `Yii::app()->baseUrl` and `$controller->createUrl()`.